# Monitor and Alert Databricks Resource Utilization and Cost Consumption

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics

We want to build monitoring and Alerting solution for Azure Databricks that should capture Resource Utilization details (like Aggregated CPU%, Memory% etc.) and Cost consumption at the Account Level.

We have Unity Catalog Enabled and there are multiple workspaces associated.

We prefer utilizing Diagnostics on Azure Log Analytics Workspace, as we do not want additional cost overhead. Diagnostic setting is enabled for Clusters, Jobs, UC, Notebooks, Accounts etc.

What are various KPIs and Metrics to consider? Please share the evaluation of the KPIs

What are the ways Alerting can be implemented using Log Analytics for Databricks

Comment: We are using overwatch and Azure API's to pull the cost and usage and Unity Catalog systems tables to pull the details https://databrickslabs.github.io/overwatch

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!